# How do I add a document reference with an auto generated ID when writing a batch in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When doing normal transactions in Firebase you can just use the .add function to add a new document with an auto generated ID; however, when doing a batch write with Web version 9 of the API I cannot find any documentation on how to add a new document with a auto generated ID. Currently I have the following code which is not working:

```js
let ref = doc(db, "projects", doc())
batch.add(ref, element);
await batch.commit();
```

This throws the error "Function doc() cannot be called with an empty path.". In Web version 8 this worked apparently by just calling .doc(). How does one accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me:

```js
let ref = doc(collection(db, "projects"))
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the Firebase documentation on [adding a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document):

> In some cases, it can be useful to create a document reference with an auto-generated ID, then use the reference later. For this use case, you can call `doc()`:
>
> ```
> import { collection, doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 
>
> // Add a new document with a generated id
> const newCityRef = doc(collection(db, "cities"));
>
> // later...
> await setDoc(newCityRef, data);
> ```

So it seems you'll need:

```
let ref = doc(db, collection("projects"))
```

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

For Node.js, or using the Firebase V8 syntax, a working solution would be:

```
let ref = db.collection("projects").doc()
batch.set(ref, {...data})
...
```